# Error accessing contents of iFrame

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, hidden

I am trying to load several links in a hidden iFrame, one after the other but an error occurs at this line

```
frame.contentDocument.getElementsByClassName('radiopad')[0].getElementsByTagName('input')[0].checked = true;
```

that states:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getElementsByTagName' of undefined
```

Essentially, I want to load a link in the iFrame, then fill the form on that page that loads in t and submit it(this code is tested and working) and then, once this has been completed, move on to doing the same thing with the next link. I am just currently not able to get the "document"(not sure if that is what is called) of the iFrame.

Here is my entire code snippet in case you need it.

```
frame = document.createElement('iframe');
frame.style.display = 'none'
document.body.appendChild(frame);
for (var i = 0; i < feedbackLinks.length; i++) {
    frame.setAttribute('src', feedbackLinks[i]);
    console.log(frame.contentDocument);
    while (frame.src != 'http://feedback.ebay.com/ws/eBayISAPI.dll') {
        frame.contentDocument.getElementsByClassName('radiopad')[0].getElementsByTagName('input')[0].checked = true;
        frame.contentDocument.getElementById('comment00').value = 'Great Seller';
        var starRatings = ['v4-15', 'v4-27', 'v4-32', 'v4-37'];
        for (var ID = 0; ID < starRatings.length; ID++) {
            if (frame.contentDocument.getElementById(starRatings[ID]) != null) {
                frame.contentDocument.getElementById(starRatings[ID]).click();
            }
        }
        frame.contentDocument.getElementById('but_formSave').click();
    }
    console.log("completed link " + (i + 1));
}
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Probably can't do that due to cross-domain policy

Answer (score 0):

I think your iframe points to different domain. You have [same-domain policy violation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy).

> The policy permits scripts running on pages originating from the same
>   site.

Please read this [wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy). It has extended answer to your problem.

Comment: Is there any way I can get around this?
Can I allow cross-domain access in the permissions in my manifest some how?

Comment: @user1702529 have a look at this wiki http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy

Comment: Can you provide me with code with which i can access the contents of the iFrame i am creating

Comment: @user1702529 do you have access to the server that iframe points to?

Comment: No I do not. I am loading ebay links in my iframe. Let me know if you need any more info

Comment: @user1702529 this is not possible then. Please read this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy. What you are really trying to achieve? Maybe there is another way around.